# cleaning out posts that don't exist anymore but links are still there

Tags: posts

First off I'll start by saying i think my site was hacked... Today i was looking at my jetpack site stats and it said i had a huge amount of visitors. a lot more than i usually do.. jet pack said that it was to posts about movie torrents. when i click on the link it says page not found. is there anyway to get rid of these old post links that don't exist anymore?

I looked at my post page and it doesn't show any of the post for-mentioned.

Here is one of the links. https://journeyfilms.com/inside-out-2015-english-hdrip-aac-download-movie-torrent/

my site is journeyfilms.com

Comment: If you backlinks are off site. Nothing you can do about them. If you have your posts have links to your old posts you may need to re-edit them.

Answer (score 0):

Since the link doesn't exist anymore, you can't get rid of it. As Sisir wrote, probably there are backlinks to that URL and you can't do anything about that (you don't need to, as well).

If your site got hacked you should always consider doing a complete recovery from backup (or, if this isn't an option do an export, re-install and import).